# How to fix this typescript "Type 'Element | {} | null' has no matching index signature for type 'string' on document.activeElement?

Tags: typescript

I was using [this amazing code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/243666) for a javascript project:

```
function focus(key: string){
  const {activeElement:{[key]: elementSibling} = {}} = document;
  if(elementSibling){
    elementSibling.focus();
  }
}

const ACTIONS: { [key: string]: (e: KeyboardEvent) => void } = {
  ArrowDown: (): void => focus('nextElementSibling'),
  ArrowUp: (): void => focus('previousElementSibling'),
  Enter: (e: KeyboardEvent): void => e.target.click()
}

function handleKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
  const handler = ACTIONS[e.key];
  if(handler) {
    e.preventDefault();
    handler(e);
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to use Typescript and I'm getting these errors:

1. on `focus()` function:

```
(parameter) key: string
Type 'Element | {} | null' has no matching index signature for type 'string'. ts(2537)
```

2. on `ACTIONS` object:

```
Property 'click' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'. ts(2339)
```

How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

The `activeElement` is the current active element in the DOM. If there is no element active, its value is `null`. `null` can not be used to with index signature as is done using `{[key]: elementSibling}`. Moreover, type of `activeElement` is `Element | null` ([Element](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.element.html)). `Element` does not define any index signature which means we can not index `activeElement` by arbitrary `string` key.

**Problem with click**- First of all, any event as a target property with type `EventTarget | null` ([Ref](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.event.html#target)). So a `e.target` can be `null` also. Second, `EventTarget` is generic interface. It does not have `click` method. You need to typecast it to `HTMLInputElement`.

### Solution

To restric `key` from being any string, add a literal type as `'nextElementSibling' | 'previousElementSibling'` and use [Optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html).

```js
function focus(key: 'nextElementSibling' | 'previousElementSibling'){
  const {activeElement} = document
  const elementSibling = activeElement?.[key] as (HTMLInputElement | null)
  if(elementSibling){
    elementSibling.focus()
  }
}

const ACTIONS = {
  ArrowDown: () => focus('nextElementSibling'),
  ArrowUp: () => focus('previousElementSibling'),
  Enter: handleEnterKeyEvent
}

function handleEnterKeyEvent(e: KeyboardEvent) {
  const target = e.target as (HTMLInputElement | null)
  target?.click()
}

function handleKeyDown (e: KeyboardEvent) {
  const handler = (<any>ACTIONS)[e.key];
  if(handler) {
    e.preventDefault();
    handler(e);
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=2#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)